# How to get the command line of a Windows Explorer context menu entry?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, context-menu

I have tried several context menu editors, etc., among others ShellMenuView, OpenWithView, Ultimate Windows Context Menu Customizer and "File Menu Tools" (that's a tool's name), but can't find the command line for some "Open [the selected file] with [a specific application], so I see the menu entry, and which works fine for that file / file type, but I don't get to the command line behind it; I want to know what the context entry, upon click, sends to the system (the exact syntax of the command send, it's not only "applicationpath" space "filepath", but more than that).

How would I do that? Registry entry? Tool?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately, the windows explorer keeps getting extended and there is more than one place that these are now kept.  Traditionally, look in HKCR\.ext (like .txt).. look at the default key string.  Then lookup HKCR\<def key string> to find it's verbs and command lines.  If the thing you are launching doesn't close immediatley, use the [system internals process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find the process and look at the command line it was launched with.  I use this all of the time to troubleshoot.

Comment: If the process started to open up the file runs more than a few seconds you can simply use Windows Taskmanager or Sysinternal ProcessExplorer to see the full command-line (including all arguments). In the end that is the simplest In Windows Taskmanager use the "Details" tab and activate the column "Commandline".

Comment: Señor CMasMas: "use the system internals process explorer to find the process and look at the command line it was launched with" - the command line in there seems only visible in a mouse-over field which quickly vanishes then, but I got it from there! Problem solved, and I will take note for further, similar problems!

Comment: Robert: "In Windows Taskmanager use the "Details" tab and activate the column "Commandline". " - this being "simpler", I first tried that, but where would I activate the column "Commandline", in the "Details" tab? (I found the "Details" tab but neither in "Options" nor by context menu in "Details" (right-click), I found a "Display Commandline" setting / option? (nor in the "View" menu)

Comment: Robert: I finally found the "Commandline" column! I have to rightclick in the CAPTION of the list field, in "Details", then I get "Select columns", and there I can add the Commandline column!

Comment: Señor CMasMas and Robert: Thank you both very much! If one of you wants to answer my question, I'll be happy to mark that answer as the "correct" one, both comments have been  very helpful indeed! THANKS!